# When I'm running an app on Android Studio the "Choose device" box doesn't show

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm trying to run a simple code on my phone (Genymotion doesn't work, so I had to run it on my phone directly) and it tells me that "External task execution finished" but Choose device box doesn't pop up when I press "Run". I installed:

1. ADB driver.
2. My phone is Xperia Sp, so I change MTP to MSC (There's no PTP).
3. USB debugging is on.

Furthermore, the Android Device Monitor is showing my device, so there's no problem with identifying my phone.

Answer (score 11):

In Android Studio:

1. Goto Run menu
2. choose edit configuration
3. select android application
4. select app in general option
5. In this option showing "Deployment Target Options" then Target,
                     choose "Show device chooser dialog".

Comment: I changed the options in "Deployment target Options', apply, re-change, and the the studio re-recognized my device

Answer (score 4):

May be your deployment target is changed.
Please check android studio setting

Click On

Run >> edit configuration >> under Android Application Click on App >> check deployemnt target option.

Answer (score 4):

In the newer version of Android Studio the "Deployment Target Options"-Section is gone.

The Dropdown-Menu for choosing the device is in the toolbar next to the "run"-Options.

[image: Deployment target had been moved from the configurations menu to the toolbar]

[image: Dropdown menu for selecting the Deployment target]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the instruction to run an application in a device: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

You can see how many devices connected from tools -> troubleshooting device connection error.

In my case, android studio found my device as a USB device but couldn't connect so I replaced the USB wire and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to run the app through USB and also  Deployment target option was not present there. I solved it by following these steps:

1. In the Navigation bar there is a search option, Search for Device Explorer, select the device explorer.
2. Re-plug the USB once and you will see there will be a list of android files of your device on the right side of the window (make sure USB debugging is on and install via USB is on).
3. Keep the device in that mode for a while, you will automatically see your device's name on the top where no device option was previously visible.
4. After this then run the app...

Hope this will work.